# Override javascript global variable in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

So I am trying to overwrite a global variable from jquery. I have the custom icon set as a specific icon, but would like to override it based on a users selection from a drop down menu.

First I have the variable declared globally:

```
var icon = customIcons['question'] || {};
```

Then used in a function:

```
function placeMarker(location) {

            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: location,
                icon: icon.icon,
                map: map,
                draggable: true
            });
}
```

Then I try to change the global variable on a click listener.

```
$(document).ready(function (icon) {
            $("#location-type-menu li").click(function () {
                icon = customIcons[this.id];
            });
});
```

Sincere thanks for any help, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: window.icon = customIcons[this.id];

Comment: Thanks, coulda sworn I tried that...

Comment: can't up vote yet, but thanks!

Comment: i don't need virtual pellets, I'm just glad to help ;)